# Spring security oauth2 for mobile

Tags: mobile, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am planning authentication solution and trying to figure out which approach would be the best.

The system is mobile app (client application) and web platform with REST api. 
The approach is to use token based authentication. My first try was Spring with its integration for OAuth2. However, it seems that Spring Security OAuth2 doesn't support token authentication without adding client credentials (which is still valid flow according OAuth spec, imho). In my case it is redundant to generate client credentials as mobile app is an integral part of the system. The desired flow should look like that :
[Token authentication sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vniLr.png)

Is it good idea to use Spring Security OAuth2 in this specific case? Is it possible to limit it smoothly only to this functionality without boilerplate code? Maybe it is good to implement this endpoint without OAuth2 module and use pure Spring Security?

Thanks in advance for any insights :)

Comment: Have you found a good solution for this?